# How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(1+3\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]:= \lbrace a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$. How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(1+3\sqrt{2})$?

I know that every equivalence class of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ contains an integer of the form $a-6b$, which is congruent to $a$ mod $6$. So does this mean that there are only 6 elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(1+3\sqrt{2})$? In general, how should I tackle problems like this?

Comment: Potentially useful to note that $(1+3\sqrt2)\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]\cap\mathbb{Z}=17\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: There is an obvious ring homomorphism $Z \to Z[\sqrt{2}]/(1 + 3\sqrt{2})$. Show that the homomorphism is surjective and determine its kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(1+3\sqrt{2})\simeq\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2,1+3X).$$ But $X+6\in(X^2-2,1+3X)$ since $X+6=X(1+3X)-3(X^2-2)$, so $$\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2,1+3X)\simeq\frac{\mathbb Z[X]/(X+6)}{(X^2-2,1+3X)/(X+6)}\simeq\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: This may be equivalent to what you're saying - couldn't you just continue simplifying the given ideal to show that $(X^2-2,1+3X)=(X+6,17)$? Think this might lead to a slightly simpler last line - that last isomorphism sign doesn't seem totally obvious.

Comment: @πr8 For me it's obvious, since all we have to do is to send $X$ to $-6$. But I can agree with the equation you wrote.

Comment: Ah - hadn't spotted that. Very clever! Nicely done.

Comment: @πr8: Could you tell me how to get the first isomorphism? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lewis $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2)\simeq\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ by sending $X$ to $\sqrt 2$. By this isomorphism $1+3\sqrt 2$ corresponds to $1+3X$.

Comment: Thank you! I found this quotient thing not very intuitive to understand, but your comments helped!